# How to make XMLRequest wait a certain amount of time until GET request is made?

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get the HTML content of a page using an XMLHTTPRequest. The page finishes loading in a few seconds, but it takes longer for the data I need to populate.

I am able to get the HTML content of the page, but the data I need is not in the response as the request is made instantly.

Is there any way to make the request wait a few seconds before trying to GET the content?

(apologies in advance if the terminology of the question is not perfect, just started using these types of requests).

```
// My current request:

async function getHTMLContent() {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        var XMLRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        XMLRequest.open('GET', "myURL", true);
        XMLRequest.send();
        XMLRequest.onload = () => {
            if (XMLRequest.readyState == 4 && XMLRequest.status == 200) {
                return resolve(XMLRequest.responseText);
            } else {
                return reject('There was an error retrieving the data');
            }
        }
    });

}
```

The current output is:

```
<div class="abc"></div>
```

with no content in between.

I would like the content do be:

```
<div class="abc">"The data"</div>.
```

Answer (score 0):

If data is added to the page after it has loaded, then that is because JavaScript in it is manipulating the DOM.

You can't simply wait for that data to appear. You need to run the JavaScript (or equivalent JavaScript).

How you depends on the specific JS you are dealing with, so you'll need to read it and reverse engineer it.